# At what angle does the line $x=a$ cut the curve $x^2=4y$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

The line $x=a$ cuts $x^2=4y$ at an angle of :

The options mentioned in the question sheet are :

a) $\arctan\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)$

b) $\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$

c) $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot \arctan(a)$

d) $\arctan\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$

I tried to find $\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}$
at $x=a$ to obtain the slope of the tangent to the curve $x^2=4y$ at the point $x=a$.

$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}$ at $x=a$ came out to be $\frac{a}{2}
$. After this, how would you proceed further to find the angle at which the line cuts the curve?

My concept for this would be to get the slope of curve and the slope of the line and then use:

$\tan(\theta) = \pm \frac{{m_1 - m_2}}{{1 + m_1 \cdot m_2}}$

where $m_1$= slope of curve i.e. $x^2=4y$

$m_2$= slope of the line i.e. $x=a$

But the line $x=a$ will have undefined slope, so I am stuck.

Requesting you all to guide me through the concept and solution of this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that the slope you have found is just $\tan(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle made by the tangent with the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking in terms of slope formulas, it's probably easier to use tangent vectors at the point of intersection, since you can then leverage the [dot product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) to find the angle between these two vectors.

The tangent vector for the vertical line $x = a$ can be chosen to be pointing vertically upwards, $⟨0, 1⟩$, or vertically downwards, $⟨0, -1⟩$.

The tangent vector for the parabola $x^2 = 4y$ can be found by parametrizing this curve in terms of $t$: $$\overrightarrow{r}(t) = ⟨t, t^2/4⟩,$$ so that its tangent vector will then be $$\overrightarrow{r'}(t) = ⟨1, t/2⟩,$$ and from there you can plug in $t = a$ at the intersection point to find the specific tangent vector.

Comment: Based on this solution, if t=a is kept,then the answer will be arctan(a/2) which matches with the answer provided in my question sheet. The concept of tangent vectors is quite fresh and interesting for me as I hadn't viewed the solution in terms of vectors.Thank you for this solution.

Comment: Comparing this solution with the solution in terms of slope, aren't there 2 answers to this question? The other solution says theta= arccot(a/2) is the answer whereas in terms of tangent vectors if t=a is kept then the specific tangent vector at that point comes out to be (1,a/2) i.e 1 as the base and a/2 as the perpendicular. Then using pythagoras theorem theta=arctan(a/2). Why the difference in answers? Am I interpreting something not correctly?

Comment: The two different numerical answers are because two lines intersecting form four angles, which split into pairs of congruent angles which are supplementary to one another. Flipping the tangent vector to the vertical line from pointing up, to pointing down, or vice versa, will toggle between these two values.

Answer (score 5):

The line $x=a$ cuts the curve $x^2=4y$ at the point $\left(a,\frac{a^2}4\right)$. The slope of the tangent line to that curve at that point is $\frac a2$. So, you are after the angle between a vertical line and a line whose slope is $\frac a2$. If $\theta$ is their angle, then $\theta=\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac a2\right)$, and therefore\begin{align}\tan\theta&=\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac a2\right)\right)\\&=\cot\left(\arctan\left(\frac a2\right)\right)\\&=\frac2a.\end{align}So,$$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac2a\right)=\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac a2\right).$$

Comment: Yes, this makes total sense. Thank you. So this means if the line was y=a instead of x=a, then the slope of the curve would also be the angle of intersection between the line y=a and the curve x^2=4y. That would simply be arctan(a/2) in that case. Is my thought process right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Comparing this solution with the solution in terms tangent vectors, aren't there 2 answers to this question? This solution says theta= arccot(a/2) is the answer whereas in terms of tangent vectors if t=a is kept then the specific tangent vector at that point comes out to be (1,a/2) i.e 1 as the base and a/2 as the perpendicular. Then using pythagoras theorem theta=arctan(a/2). Why the difference in answers? Am I interpreting something not correctly?

Comment: Given two non-parallel straight lines, the problem of determining their angle has one and only one solution. Why should there be two solutions in this case?

Comment: Yes, there should be one and only one solution. Thank you.